# Going through workbook and making a column in the first sheet out of the content of a particular cell across all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This gives me an error:

> (Constant expression required)

Code:

```
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim t As Long
Dim Max As Long
Max = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Dim Dates(2 To Max) As String

For t = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  Set Sheet3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(t)
  If Sheet3.Name = "USA" & t Then
    Dates(t) = Sheet3.Range("E4").Value
  End If
Next t
```

Comment: I know I can use ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) to go down the column each time but I don't know how to extract the data

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeVariable = Sheet.Range("B22").Value
```

If you need a way to iterate the sheets you can do this.

```
iFoundWorksheet = 0
For iIndex = 1 To ea.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set ws = ea.Worksheets(iIndex)
    If UCase(ws.Name) = "RESULTS" Then
        iFoundWorksheet = iIndex
        Exit For
    End If
Next iIndex
If iFoundWorksheet = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No worksheet was found with the name RESULTS (this is not case sensetive). Aborting."
    GoTo Abort
End If
Set ws = ea.Worksheets(iFoundWorksheet)
ws.Activate
```

---

For you new issue Constant expression required
Your array definition has to be defined with constants.

```
Dim Max As Long
Const Max1 = 5
Dim Dates(2 To Max1) As String
```

This would work. But you are not going to be able to load

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

Into a const

You are probably going to need to ReDim your Dates Array.

Comment: please look at my code. I figured out a way to store the values in an array but it gives me an error. thanks

Comment: @Dean What error is it giving your.  It is always helpful to provide the error you are getting from code.

Comment: Constant expression required, it highlights  the word Max

Comment: See additions to my original answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SummarySheet as Sheet

For r = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(r)
If Sheet.Name = "Page"& r Then
     SummarySheet.Cells(Row you want to paste,Column you want to paste) = Sheet.Range("Cell you want to copy").Value
End if
Next r
```

I was in doubt if your t and r were different, but if so then you should make a For loop for both, or make r a calculated value from t

Edit: If you want to paste in H9 and go from there, you column will be 8 and your row 9. If you then put 9+r it will always take the next row below. Assuming r starts at 1 and has all number in a row. You can play a bit with these values until you get it right.

Comment: Yes thank you that was a typo, so What I am trying to do is let say go through the entire workbook and from each sheet copy let say Call A1 and then paste those values in a column that start at H9.

Comment: You want all the values in H9, or you want them to start in H9 and then go down or left?

Comment: I see your point i will need that too. but my big issue is going through the entire workbook and let say for sheet2 A1=1   for      sheet3  A1=2 for        sheet4 A1=3     then sheet1 will display a column of 1,2,3

Comment: please look at my code. I figured out a way to store the values in an array but it gives me an error. thanks